# MSDN Help Integration Guidance

Tags: msdn, vsx

I'm aware of Sandcastle and DocProject, but I need some guidance on the structure of what I want to do before I can look up how to do it.

What I need to build is is MSDN-style help integrated with context-sensitive F1 help for the Types and Members of my library.

I already have the library, a bunch of inline XML documentation, and a wix installer script that installs the intellisense xml files.  I need the help file-generating project/scripts, the tags/markup necessary to make the help-system context sensitive, and the list of items that need to be added to the/an installer to make it install, uninstall, and upgrade properly.

If possible, I'd like to use the MSDN "Online Source" feature to always get the latest and greatest from my website rather than having to create a separate installer or reship the same software product just because of a documentation change.

I've looked at HelpStudio and DocumentX, but on the product websites I haven't found mention of installation integration or "Online Source" features as described above.  Also, as with WiX, I feel that although the learning curve might be a bit steeper, a sandcastle & friends will offer more flexibility and power down the road.

So what mix of software/features/tips do I need to accomplish this?